# When was Cloud City first mentioned as a resort/casino?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In *Empire Strikes Back* Cloud City is shown to be a mining colony for tibanna gas, and that's it.

However, in most books that refer to Cloud City, they mention that it is a resort and casino city.  When did this first start?

Comment: According to Wookiepedia it's first mention seems to be in [The Jewel of Yavin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jewel_of_Yavin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New canon references appear to be introduced in these properties:

**Star Wars, Absolutely Everything You Need to Know** (reference)

**Lando** (comic)

**Empire's End** (novel)

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_City/

In terms of ***Legends*** era - as far as "official" - StarWars.com [referenced gambling on Cloud City in 1999](https://web.archive.org/web/19990209112135/http://starwars.com/locations/cloud_city/index.html):

Additionally, further back, there seem to be several references in West End RPG materials:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_Guide_to_the_Star_Wars_Universe - 1984

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Crisis_on_Cloud_City - 1989

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_Guide_2:_Yavin_and_Bespin - 1989

Comment: The '92 book "Zorba the Hutt's Revenge" mentions that Jabba had a casino on Cloud City. Since it was a young adult book, I was curious if there were others that said it first.  Link: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zorba_the_Hutt%27s_Revenge